# How do I add a shader controller to extend the normal zone?

Tags: shaders, normals, normal-map, shader-nodes

I set up the shader to render Z normal. I need to somehow add a controller to extend the coverage of Z normals - so that the gradient can be dropped below the border or above the border of zero.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current setup, the Z component will vary over the sphere from 1 at the top to -1 at the bottom, so the simplest way will be to simply use a Map Range to vary the output over the desired range :

[image: material and result]

Simply vary the 'From Min' input from 1 to -1 to vary the extent of the gradient.